# Elevated Button Dark Theme

Tags: flutter

What is the theme code for the ElevatedButton?
I do not know how to put Icon Button and Elevated Button in MyThemes class so that I can change their colors

[image: home]

```
Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 20,
                        left: 20,
                        right: 20
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => Biography()));
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            // background color
                            primary: color_white,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Image.asset('pic/biography.png'),
                                iconSize: 70,
                                onPressed: null,
                              ),
                              AutoSizeText(
                                "بـیـوگرافی"
                                ,maxLines: 1
                                ,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                minFontSize: 10,
                                style:TextStyle(fontSize: 25,color: color_black,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),


                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

And how to give them all a theme for the ElevatedButton and Expanded sections

Comment: You could check the brightness of the Theme which indicates if you are in light or dark mode. For example: `Theme.of(context).brightness==Brightness.light /* Check if its in light mode */ ? Colors.black: Colors.white`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining your application `ThemeData` you have a named property named `elevatedButtonTheme` which is an `ElevatedButtonThemeData`.

**Custom Theme code Sample**

```dart
class MyTheme {
  static final ThemeData light = _buildLightTheme();
  static final ThemeData dark = _buildDarkTheme();

  static ThemeData _buildLightTheme() {
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light();
    return base;
  }

  static ThemeData _buildDarkTheme() {
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData.dark();
    return base.copyWith(
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          // Makes all my ElevatedButton green
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/d81483fb4fcaca8b1d50d8a88b44e0c6?null_safety=true)